# Programatically reorder layers in qgis?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort layers in QGIS table of contents?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41977/sort-layers-in-qgis-table-of-contents)

I write a qgis python plugin ,and i try to connect keybord keys to reoder layers in qgis .
Are there a method in qgis allows me to retrieve the ordered list of layers and another that set the order?

Comment: this could help http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/41977/5850