# How to add layer/raster with specific position in the QGIS layer list?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, table-of-contents

I use addRasterLayer(rast,'Name') but this adds the raster to the top.
It is possible to **set position** when I add raster at once? Is it possible??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the new Layer tree (aka legend or Toc) added by Martin Dobias since QGIS v.2.4, you can load a raster layer to any position of the ToC following these steps:

1. Get a reference of the layer tree

   `root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()`
2. Create the raster layer object

   `from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
   fileName = "/path/to/raster/file.tif"
   fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
   baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
   mylayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)`
3. Add the layer to the QGIS Map Layer Registry (the second argument must be set to False for you to specify a custom position in step 4.)

   `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mylayer, False)`
4. Insert the layer in the third position of the ToC

   `root.insertLayer(2, mylayer)`

Answer (score 3):

I will need to look into that, but you could try to add the layer and than change the order afterwards, if you want to use python anyway. Check out [this other thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41977/sort-layers-in-qgis-table-of-contents) about changing the order of layers in the TOC for hints.