# How to load a raster layer at the top of the QGIS ToC?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, layers, table-of-contents

The following code inserts my `new_layer` just above the active layer in the QGIS ToC.

```
new_layer = iface.addRasterLayer(...)
```

Instead, I'd like my `new_layer` to be inserted at the top of the QGIS ToC.

Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: did you check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41977/sort-layers-in-qgis-table-of-contents?

Comment: Is it necessary to create groups to move up a layer ? I thought of something like: li = iface.legendInterface(); li.moveLayerIndex(new_layer, 0), just as simple as manuallly dragging up a layer in the left column to put it in first rank. Does a similar method exist ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using the new Layer tree (aka legend or ToC) added by Martin Dobias since QGIS v.2.4, you can load a layer to the top of the ToC following these steps:

1. Get a reference of the layer tree

   ```
   root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
   ```
2. Create the layer object

   ```
   from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
   fileName = "/path/to/raster/file.tif"
   fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
   baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
   mylayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
   ```
3. Add the layer to the QGIS Map Layer Registry

   ```
   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mylayer, False)
   ```
4. Insert the layer at the top of the ToC (position `0`)

   ```
   root.insertLayer(0, mylayer)
   ```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to do it after having added the layers but two alternative options are:

- Create groups, then you can use moveLayers to put layers in a group
- Add the layers in the right order !