# How to sort layers within groups with Python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, legend, pyqt, sorting

After running a longer script (Qgis Console), all I want to do is **sort the layers within my groups**; 
since some of them are buffers and the 'biggest' buffer is now on top.

I've tried stuff based on: 
Post on how [to sort Layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88738/is-there-a-simple-way-to-sort-layers-alphabetically-in-qgis)

And Martin Dobias's post concerning the tree layer api: 
[Layer Tree API 1](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/) ; [Layer Tree API 2](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2) ; [Layer Tree API 3](http://www.hlutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3)

It sounds simple enough but for some reason I can not figure it out...

Among many things I've tried this:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for child in root.children():
  if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
      lyr = child.children()
      lyr.sortItems(0,Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

But .children() appearantly returns a list(?)

The iface.legendInterface() group-options didn't help either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorting layers is a particularly painful task in PyQGIS, because of the lack of suitable methods in the `QgsLayerTreeNode` class. Based on your code, I managed to write a console script that seems to work (after multiple tests...).

**Disclaimer #1:** backup your project before testing this script.

**Disclaimer #2:** this script only sorts 1st-level groups (I didn't test it on subgroups).

Here we are:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

for child in root.children():
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
        lyrList = [c.layer() for c in child.children()]
        lyrSortList = sorted(lyrList, key=lambda x: x.name()) # sorts layers based on name

        for idx, lyr in enumerate(lyrSortList):
            treeLyr = child.insertLayer(idx, lyr) # adds sorted layers to group

        child.removeChildren(len(lyrList),len(lyrList)) # removes previous layers
```

Note that the sorted layers will be visible. Use the `setVisible()` method to change that behavior.

Comment: Yo, worked perfectly. Can't believe it finally can be done! And since I don't have subgroups - let's save this for another day. THANKS SO MUCH.

Comment: Good to hear that! I hope layer sorting will be easier in the next QGIS versions...

Comment: So say we all...