# Programmatically change layer position in the table of contents (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2, pyqt, table-of-contents

I am trying move/position a layer to the bottom of the TOC by using addTopLevelItem on all other layers. I unsure how to reference the layers as QTreeWidgetItem's.

```
def bg_bottom_level_item(self):
    layers = self.canvas.layers()
    layerlist = []
    for layer in layers:
        layerID = str(layer.id())
        if "Auto_Background" not in layerID:
            layerlist.append(layer)
        else:
            pass
    for layer in layerlist:
        leg = qgis.utils.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QTreeWidget, 'theMapLegend')
        item = QTreeWidgetItem(layer)
        leg.addTopLevelItem(item)
```

Error:

`QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsRasterLayer'`

Or does anyone have another solution for moving layers around in the TOC?

Comment: Check out this post, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41977/sort-layers-in-qgis-table-of-contents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the new Layer tree (aka legend or Toc) added by Martin Dobias since QGIS v.2.4, you can **load a layer to the bottom of the ToC** following these steps:

1. Get a reference of the layer tree

   ```
   root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
   ```
2. Create the layer object

   ```
   mylayer = QgsVectorLayer("/Path/to/your/data.shp", "my layer", "ogr")
   ```
3. Add the layer to the QGIS Map Layer Registry

   ```
   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mylayer, False)
   ```
4. Append the layer to the layer tree

   ```
   root.addLayer(mylayer)
   ```

If you want **to move an existing layer to the bottom of the ToC**, you need to know the layer id (you can get it by executing root.findLayerIds()). Once you get the layer id, follow these steps:

a.  Same as 1.

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
```

b.  Get layer by id

```
myExistingLayer = root.findLayer("divipola_mpio20141217144143371")
```

c. Clone it (trust me)

```
myClone = myExistingLayer.clone()
```

d. Append the clone to the layer tree

```
root.addChildNode(myClone)
```

e. Get the original layer's parent

```
parent = myExistingLayer.parent()
```

f. Remove the original layer

```
parent.removeChildNode(myExistingLayer)
```

*Edit: Now steps a. to f. should work for any layer/group regardless of its position in the layer tree hierarchy.*

Comment: Can you explain why we need to clone it? I used this technique, but in a code review got rejected, since I am cloning.

Comment: See https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/

Comment: The article doesn't explain why they use clone.

Comment: To move a layer in the Layers panel you need to make a copy of the existing layer, insert it at the desired position and then remove the original layer object. To make the copy you use clone.

Comment: Yes I know all this, but why must we clone it, it seems that making a copy and then deleting the old one creates more overhead than necessary. Why not just have a move method or something without cloning?

Comment: You can ask the author of the layer tree component. That's why I sent you the link ;)