# Set layer order in QGIS with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, table-of-contents

There are several similar questions around, like [Sort layers in QGIS table of contents](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41977/sort-layers-in-qgis-table-of-contents) or [Order layer in QGIS with PyQgis](https://www.queryxchange.com/q/23_181281/sort-layers-in-group-qgis-python/), but I can't get it to work. Here is what I do:

```py
# image and shapefile are already defined
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
li = iface.legendInterface()
iface.addVectorLayer(shapefile)
iface.addRasterLayer(image)
lakes = [l for l in li.layers() if l.name() == 'lakes'][0]
raster = QgsRasterLayer(image, QFileInfo(image).baseName())

# set "lakes" layer on top:
for l in li.layers():
    if l.name() == lakes.name():
        li.moveLayer(l, 0)
```

The condition from "if" is fulfilled (I checked it several times using some print commands), but the "lakes" layer won't move to the top. Actually, nothing happens at all. Am I using the wrong function to set the layer order?

---

According to [QGIS Layer Tree API (Part 2)](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/), I tried this

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for ch in root.children():
    if ch.layerName() == lakes.name():
        root.insertChildNode(0, ch)
        root.removeChildNode(ch)
```

which does the job for me. But why does moveLayer not do what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [QgsLegendInterface::moveLayer()](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsLegendInterface.html#a23183b102f51dfecb81b26ea570ff224) method is used to move layers to a **group index**.

So if you create a new group and use your code, the layer should move inside this group. But if no groups are present, your layer will not move.

Comment: I see. Was not obvious to me, so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @s6hebern - Most welcome! It was not so obvious to me either until I checked the API and it mentioned the `int` value being an index for groups and not layers :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the code as follows:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for ch in root.children():
    if ch.name() == lakes.name():
        _ch = ch.clone()
        root.insertChildNode(0, _ch)
        root.removeChildNode(ch)
```

[QGIS Layer Tree API (Part 2)](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/) says "moving a node is done in three steps"

1. Clone the existing layer,
2. Insert the cloned layer to layer tree,
3. Remove the original layer.

Comment: cloning is a common way to get the task done. When I used clone method, I was told to try and do it another way. Any ideas, or can you provide some reason why clone is the correct way? It seems to me that there is a lot of overhead while cloning and there might be a better way.