# Sort layers in table of contents in QGIS 3?

Tags: layers, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, table-of-contents

When I load a bunch of layers into QGIS, they seem to load in reverse alphabetical order. I'd like to sort them alphabetically.

In [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41977/sort-layers-in-qgis-table-of-contents) a solution is proposed, but that does not work in QGIS 2.18 or 3.4:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.utils import iface


mw = iface.mainWindow()
lgd = mw.findChild(QTreeWidget, "theMapLegend")  # get ref to object by type/objectName
lgd.sortItems(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)  # sort first column (Qt.DescendingOrder to reverse)
```

How can I do this in QGIS 3?
I tried:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import * 
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

mw = iface.mainWindow()
lgd = mw.findChild(QTreeView, 'theLayerTreeView')
lgd.sortItems(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

It "works" until the last line, then I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTreeView' object has no attribute 'sortItems'

I don't know where to search for a method that will sort the layers as in the first code example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following to sort all loaded layers alphabetically:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
LayerNamesEnumDict=lambda listCh:{listCh[q[0]].name()+str(q[0]):q[1]
                                   for q in enumerate(listCh)}

mLNED = LayerNamesEnumDict(root.children())
mLNEDkeys = OrderedDict(sorted(LayerNamesEnumDict(root.children()).items())).keys()

mLNEDsorted = [mLNED[k].clone() for k in mLNEDkeys]
root.insertChildNodes(0,mLNEDsorted)
for n in mLNED.values():
    root.removeChildNode(n)
```

---

Credit to [@MikhailMinin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/76883/mikhail-minin) with his [Sort Layers plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SortLayers/) in which the above code is based.

Comment: This works for me (QGIS 3.10.3-A Coruña) but only for top level Layers in the Layers panel. For child Layers (e.g., Layers inside a Group), they remain unsorted. Any tips on how to tweak the code to sort recursively?

Comment: @davidafuller01 - I would suggest you ask this as [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). It could be that there's an existing function or plugin which achieves this.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to load **and sort** a lot of layers into QGIS 3 is using the **"Load Them All"** plugin: 
*"recursively loads vector and raster layers stored in a directory structure, based on several filters".* One of the options is to sort the loaded layers by name! Perfect!

Comment: The only thing I still miss is the option to load the raster layers as singleband pseudocolor with different color maps and min/max values set to actual min/max of the raster.
see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318842/load-ascii-rasters-in-qgis-as-singleband-pseudocolor-by-default/319033#319033

Comment: This answer actually solved the original question: the plugin loads a lot of layers in alphabetical order. Why does this answer get downvoted?

Comment: For reference, I think what you missed in your comment (it was last year) is already implemented in Load Them All. See [load rasters with predefined style](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4d24726f3734ca6cbba44c9d36b62c1a20ef2f90/687474703a2f2f646f776e6c6f6164732e74757866616d696c792e6f72672f7475786769732f67656f626c6f67732f706c7567696e5f4c6f61645468656d416c6c2f696d67732f4c6f61645468656d416c6c5f4170706c7947726f75705374796c65732e676966).

Answer (score 2):

For load using ascening order you only need this (**sortByColumn** method):

```
view = iface.layerTreeView()
view.setSortingEnabled(True)
view.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder) # sort first column (Qt.DescendingOrder to reverse)
```

Add after load some layers,you will see that they are loaded correctly ordered.

**tested using QGIS 3.6.1**

I hope this helps

Comment: I tested using **QGIS 2.18** and got the following error: "Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'Qt' is not defined" 
I got no error when I included the import code from the original code. But then the code did not sort the layers in the TOC.

Comment: I tested also in **QGIS 3.4.6:**
I got no errors, but the code did not sort the layers that were already in the TOC, and neither layers that were added afterwards.

Comment: Your question is about qgis 3,no qgis 2.18!this code short layer on toc,you need execute and after add layers!Clean toc,execute and add layers

Comment: I also tried in Qgis 3.4.6, but it doesn't seem to work. I run the code in the python console. Then I add 3 layers (3 ascii rasters) and they are added in reversed alphabetical order in the TOC.