# Sorting layers by name or type in QGIS Layers Panel

Tags: qgis

Oddly I'm not able to find an answer to how to simply sort layers by names or by type in the "Layers Panel". Can someone point me in the right direction?

QGIS version 3.14.15-Pi

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318961/29431).

Comment: @Kadir Şahbaz, Thanks for that. I was hoping that I wouldn't need to write code something like this. I would have thought it to be a pretty basic feature for a list panel.

Comment: @Phil_in_Tx  the "Load Them All" plugin from the link Kadir gave involves no plugin - comments states that below the answer.